# google cloud platform for saving my database of android app

Tags: android

I am a new Android  app developer and I  have a freelance android app project as task for me

the app idea is something like social networking  app

I don't know from where to start .. after I did some research and found parse. com as backend server cloud but then I found that it is temporarily closed  then  I found google cloud platform  as an alternative,

but I don't know how to start what to do

example I want first to create  login screen how I can save login data to the server?

Is it right to create mysql database as usually then import them to the platform

really  I need  a help and don't know how to start 
and this is my first freelance app project if I success in it I can be an employer to the company I
need some tutorial or reference or sample code to understand the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Parse.com is going to shutdown it's services in next January, why don't you go for Backendless or App24 (Both have tutorial on their websites for android and other platforms). Both of them are free with complete backend data control without any required special server side still.

Comment: is backendless as easy as parse. com and is strong enough and which better it's or Google cloud platform thanks